# Dynamic Select Drop Box Generation Containing PHP Data

Tags: javascript, php, select, dynamic, addition

I need some help generating multiple select boxes. I am able to generate new boxes but they do not contain the SQL data that the boxes should have. I will link my javascript code first.

```
    <script>

                        function add_file_field2(){
                            var container2=document.getElementById('file_container2');
                            var file_field2=document.createElement('select');
                            file_field2.name='animalCommony[]';
                            file_field2.type='animalCommony';
                            file_field2.value = 'animalCommony[]';
                            file_field2.text = 'animalCommony';
                            container2.appendChild(file_field2);
                            var br_field=document.createElement('br');
                            container2.appendChild(br_field);
                        }

                        function remove_field2() {
                            var container2=document.getElementById('file_container2');
                            lastChild = container2.lastChild;
                            if(lastChild !=0) {
                                container2.removeChild(lastChild);
                                file_field-= 1;
                            }
                        }
</script>
```

So I am not sure how I need to modify that code to generate the correct select boxes.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    $db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
    $db->connect();
    $db->query("SELECT [ID], [Common_Name], [Scientific_Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals");
    while($row = $db->fetch())
    {
    ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['Common_Name'];?> - <?php echo $row['Scientific_Name'];?>"><?php echo $row['Common_Name'];?> - <em><?php echo $row['Scientific_Name'];?></em></option>

    <?php 
    }
    ?>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="add_file_field2();">Add Another Animal</a>
                          <br />
                          <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="remove_field2();">Remove Animal</a><br />
                            <br>
                          </p>
```

Finally I will have a screenshot of what it looks like after hitting the 'add another animal button' twice. Thank you for your help!
[image]

As you can see empty select boxes are generated.

Screen shot including an example of the kind of data that should populate the added boxes.
[image]

Screenshot of database
[image]

Comment: what "SQL data" should be in the select boxes?

Comment: The sql data is just the names of animals pulling from a column in a sql database with a primary key.

Comment: @LynHeadley - I'll post another screen shot with an example selected in the first drop down.

Comment: If you want help with the sql statement, you'll need to describe the table you want to query. If you need help with the javascript, provide a working sql query.

Comment: Ok I'll post a screen shot of the table.

Comment: @LynHeadley - Screen shot of the database is up the table is named All_Animals.

Comment: please describe what should appear in the select list. You've already got a selection list containing all the animals. now what do you want to happen when 'another animal' is clicked?

Comment: @LynHeadley- When I click another animal, I was an exact copy of the current working selection box to be made. One that contains all the animals from the SQL database populated into each animal added selection box.

Comment: does the current working selection box have an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is copy the contents of the selection box, you don't need to query SQL again. Here's a javascript function that will do the copy, assuming your original selection box has id "myselect." I've also left you a jsfiddle below.

```
window.add_file_field2 = function () {

    function  copySelect(select) {
        var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
        newSelect.name = 'animalCommony[]';
        newSelect.type = 'animalCommony';
        newSelect.value = 'animalCommony[]';
        newSelect.text = 'animalCommony';

        for (var i = 0;i < select.options.length;i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option')
            option.value = select.options[i].value
            option.text = select.options[i].text
            newSelect.appendChild(option)
        }
        return newSelect
    }

    var container2 = document.getElementById('file_container2');
    container2.appendChild(copySelect(document.getElementById("myselect")));
    var br_field = document.createElement('br');
    container2.appendChild(br_field);
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLLQg/9/)